# Использования двух серверных языков при создании сайта

Tags: python, php

Товарищи, просьба помочь советом трудящимся.

Если ли проигрыш в производительности, нагрузки на сервер и т.д., если использовать язык программирования python (допустим, что для обработки отдельной базы), в случаи что движок сайта написан на php?

Только не спрашивайте, что за извращенные фантазии привели к такому решению.

Comment: Дело не в языке, а в задаче.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Меня интересует ответ на вышеприведенный

Comment: @Gaponec, Вы бы хоть ОС указали. Да и остальные детали конфигурации железа, софта и нагрузки (желательно количественно, т.е. с цифрами)  не помешают.

Если вообще -- не думаю, что появление еще одного активного интерпретатора существенно повлияет на производительность сервера в целом.

Если же Ваш питон будет активизироваться "два раза в час", то говорить попросту не о чем.

Comment: C трудом представляю себе выигрыш от этой комбинации, если над каждой стороной не трудится по команде девелоперов минимум. И если вариант нанять команду девелоперов реален, то, возможно, имеет смысл что-то переписать модулями на том же С.

Comment: У меня питон висит апишкой на страже БД, и со всех сторон к нему ломиться народ, в том числе локальные для него сайты на php и node. Вроде не жалуюсь. Правда при ресах в 8Gb Ram/ i7 4770 (3.4)/ много Tb хард / Черть. на c10k срать.

Comment: @Rijen wat?

Comment: @Fike web на C? Месье понимает толк в извращениях.

Comment: @alexlz, не весь веб, а модуль для языка. Phalcon, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не будет никакого проигрыша. Мало того, совмещение разных технологий используют довольно часто на крупных проектах. Это удобно, т.к. разные технологии лучше подходят для разных задач. Чтобы использовать реализацию на разных языках, обычно используют [очереди сообщений](http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2009/05/15/%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC/).

Answer (score 1):

В любом случае выбрал бы python (php не знаю и не доверяю).
Что касается быстродействия, то cython вполне способен решить проблемы скорости.